Does the primary of an ideal transfomer have a zero reactance?
In the attached figure, the new primary of XFMR1 connected in parallel with the inductor L1 models the original primary of an ideal transfomer. My question is, when modeling the infinite inductance in the original primary by an inductor in parallel with the new primary, what are the characteristics of the new primary, i.e., the primary of XFMR1? Does it has a zero reactance?

Source of the figure:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/135515/320652

As shown in the circuit, XFMR1 is open circuit, because the secondary is open circuit. When I2 is zero, I1 is zero. By definition, the characteristic of an ideal transform is I1==I2*n/m.

Your question is not making sense to me. If there is infinite magnetizing inductance then it doesn't need a model.

@Andyaka isn't that what you suggested as what an ideal transfomer is in my previous question?....You mentioned that it has an infinite magnetic inductance because of the infinite permeability of the iron core. But an infinite permeability means an infinite reactance as well. How one can model this infinite reactance. As the figure depicts, one can connect an inductor in parallel with the primary. My question is, if one subtracts the infinity out of the primary by adding the parallel inductor, what would be the properties of the then left primary? Would it have no reactance at all?

An infinite inductance is an open circuit and, this requires no model.

@Jack and no I never made that suggestion. I said: One version of an ideal transformer has infinite magnetization inductance. Which one are you assuming?

@Andyaka I've edited my question, does it make more sense now?

Sorry but it doesn't make sense.
